# Trace-width calculation of a relay output for a 6A device

Tags: current, relay

I have almost designed a PCB and I am willing to finalize soon.
A part of it has a relay and the contacts are directly connected to a card-edge connector.

The current will be contacted is about 5A and maximum 6A momentarily during start of a device. And that device can stay contacted for about 20 hours a day.

If I calculate `Trace-width` from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/stripline-max-current-calculator/)
The result can be seen below. It recommends 8mm `trace-width`. Is that really so?
And secondly, I like to protect the circuit by using a `chip-fuse`. What rate would you recommend?

**A sample chip-fuse:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are finalizing a PCB and starting to calculate trace widths and picking components..?

Comment: It is a last minute addition if you necessarily like to know about it. However, I prefer you to focus on the question if I may?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculator seems a little conservative.  It's closer to the results I'm getting for an internal trace (9.25-9.5mm) than for external traces (3.5-3.7mm).  Not sure which rules it's using, but I've got 5 sites that agree fairly well.
[4pcb](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html)
[7pcb](https://www.7pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.php)
[Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width)
[Qorvo](https://www.qorvo.com/design-hub/design-tools/interactive/pcb-trace-power-handling-calculator)
[DeSmith](https://www.desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/TraceWidth.html)

Comment: You are right about the calculator, there is something wrong with it. In fact that I wanted to enter trace-width 9 but then the max-current jumped to 20Amps. I guess it is buggy or so. I therefore set the trace-width back to 8. I am going to use bottom layer which would be external trace. I will make it 4mm then. Would you like to also give your opinion about my second question regarding fuse?

Comment: Any fuse over 6A will allow normal operation.  After that, it's a matter of how quickly you need it to open under certain overcurrent conditions.  If you don't have any surges over 6A, a popular option with plenty of examples is 6.3A, although 6.25A and 6.5A are available.  You don't mention voltage, but make sure you don't exceed the fuse voltage limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advises. I don't think there will be extra surge over 6A. For the fuse, I am not sure how quick it should open. I think, for safety reasons, it's better be quick. Besides, I should also think that if it would be re-settable or not.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding fuse sizing:

If your device only ever draws 6 A at startup, you can use any fuse higher than that, how close to 6A you dear to venture depends on how confident you are that the device will only ever draw 6A.

It also a matter of what you're protecting from, it you just want to make sure the whole house doesn't burn down, 7.5A is probably close enough. If you want to try and limit damage to the device itself, you might need to cut it closer. If you have a fuse holder on the board, you can experiment for yourself.

Fuses also need to be re-rated depending on ambient temperature. A fuse in a hot environment will have a lower de facto current rating than a fuse at room temperature, and a fuse in a cold environment will have a higher current rating. This is because a fuse is actually a device which fails open when it gets too hot, and the current rating is just a convenient way of describing that. So a fuse that's kept in a cold environment will be able to handle more current before it melts compared (as it's being cooled by its environment) to a fuse that's kept at room temperature.